Editing the UV Maps and there's a cutoff in the center. Is there a way to prevent or account for this?
So I'm trying to make custom clothes for a potential job, and one thing I thought I would try is creating some simple clothes and editing the UV Maps to create some custom designs.
I started creating this tank top and the colors match fine, which I can assume is because the design matches cleanly throughout. However, I wanted to try adding a logo on to the model just to make it less simple. Here are the UV maps for the tank top.


If you're wondering why the pieces are split in two, I created this object in Marvelous Designer and all the tutorials I've followed had the shirts split in two. I assume this is to allow for better manipulation of the garment on a virtual avatar.
However, when I export the UV Maps into Blender, the central logo in getting cutoff at the middle.

I have seen 3D objects, including clothes, with logos on them, but all the information I can find has you adding the logo on in Marvelous Designer or through Blender itself, but I'm wondering if its possible to just do on the UV Map in the first place? Am I going about this the wrong way? Or is there something I'm missing?
Thanks in advance for the help.

You could either move the UV maps in the UV Editor until the 2 parts stick to each other, or simply correct the image in an image editor like Photoshop or Krita?
